# Selenium can not identify frame

Tags: c#, selenium

Everything worked fine until the site ran an update ... now I can not access frame anymore ... says it can not find the element

```
<iframe width="100%" src="Paginas/CobrancaBSB/titulos.asp" style="border: 0px; height: 316px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" scollbar="no" id="iframePrinc" name="iframePrinc" onload="iframeLoad();" __idm_frm__="690"></iframe>
```

Inspect element:

[image: Inspect element]

My code:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("iframePrinc")));
```

Frame Hierarchy:

```
Body
   |____ iframe = Principal
       |____ frameSet = frmSet
           |____ frame = Corpo
               |____frame = iframePrinc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error looks quite obvious from the screenshot. The iframe that you are looking at is inside another frame (which is inside a frameSet) and you are trying to directly switch the frame without switching to its parent frame. You need switch based on the hierarchy. Use below

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("<parentFrameNameHere>")));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Name("iframePrinc")));
```

[image: Frame in frame]

Comment: Out of curiosity how can you tell that the frame is within another frame?

Comment: I already tried this, in case I switched to the default content and then tried to enter the first frame ... but even then he could not find the element on the page. I updated the post with the hierarchy of frames

Comment: I just solved the problem ... I made a collection to enumerate all the iframes, so I could see that I could not find any iframe ... I put a Thread.Sleep just to check the problem. It would try to select the iframe while the page was still loading. :) thanks man